# I can't get utterscroll to work? How to include it?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to set up utterscroll and I can't seem to be able to do so.

There is no clear instruction, I put both provided files in order and I call the event but nothing https://github.com/debiki/utterscroll

I can't even get it to work on a JSFIDDLE.

Anybody please help me, I can't get this to work, I did everything, I even copied the demo and downloaded each external file, and it got the point where it look just like the demo but scrolling doesn't work??

What is wrong?
http://www.debiki.com/dev/utterscroll

Comment: can you share some code?

Comment: Did you ask the original developer?

Comment: yes @badZoke here is a jsfiddle with both files from github in there and in order also on the top jquery minified and the bottom the call but still nothing http://jsfiddle.net/bvtVb/ i seriously been at  it for hours no lie

Comment: @Nirk no he hasnt logged on in 3 months, but i see his demo working but if i try to replicate his demos nothing, here is jsfiddle with all the code nedded and still nothing i dont know if utterscroll even work rather then the demo

Comment: wow so i wasted all day today on a "simple" plugin i couldnt even get it to show signs of working :(

Comment: You have not included Modernizr

Comment: have you included jQuery? can you share the order you've included your script files?

Comment: jquery>modernizer>scrollable>uuterscroll>myjs> @badZoke

Comment: @PraveenGowdaIV i just did and nothing happens

Comment: are you getting any errors in console?

Comment: @badZoke i wish you had my solution man, tho i realize i cant ask too much but i really need help here is my whole folder im working on demo.php https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B-C0T_-acxRqYjQ5YnVJVl9vWHc&usp=sharing

Comment: i got it to work here http://jsfiddle.net/bvtVb/1/ but never on my side, i have no idea what im doing wrong, every file is valid and its all really there

Comment: maybe a css propertie of my own is interfeering? but why is it working on jsfiddle know what i mean @badZoke

Comment: @therealest added an answer please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all your script file references at the very end, before the `</body>`,

```
    .
    .
    .        
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-scrollable.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/debiki-utterscroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/essentials.js"></script>
</body>
```

It should work just fine.

Comment: wow what a difference, i had no idea it would make such, thanks alot @badZoke may alot of women lay in bed with you

Comment: haha :) these are a part of best practices.. CSS at the top, JS at the bottom.. ALWAYS :D